# JavaScript copy to clipboard not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom, copy-paste

I have a function in my script that gives me an error. The function purpose is to copy text from static panel(not textbox or input) with onClick event.

**Uncaught TypeError: copyText.select is not a function**

The thing i want is to make the user able to click the text and it's get copied to his clipboard.

Maybe you can offer better function that works?

https://codepen.io/abooo/pen/jYMMMN?editors=1010

```
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("display");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

From w3schools

Comment: `<h1>` doesn't have a `.value()` function (Nor does `<h1>` have a `.select()` function). Perhaps you're thinking of an input?

Comment: Change `h1` to a `textarea` for example...that way it works..

Comment: No need to swap the `header1` tag for a `textarea`. You can use a hidden input to hold the `textContent` of the element that calls the function which will enable you to use `.select()` and `document.execCommand('copy')` [**CodePen Example**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RxGGyq?editors=1010) **Updated for multiple use**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This will allow you to copy the text of an element. Though I have not tested it with complicated layout.

If you want to use this then remove the alerts and provide a better way to let the user know the content was copied.

> SAFARI: This does not work on Safari before version 10.0. But as of [Safari 10.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_10_0.html) this now works.

```js
function copyText(element) {
  var range, selection, worked;

  if (document.body.createTextRange) {
    range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(element);
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    selection = window.getSelection();        
    range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(element);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
  
  try {
    document.execCommand('copy');
    alert('text copied');
  }
  catch (err) {
    alert('unable to copy text');
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id='display' onClick='copyText(this)'>Text Sample</h1>
```

If you want to use this on an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element then let me know the code is different.

The try/catch is for older versions of Safari that would throw an exception. So if you don't plan to support Safari before version 10.0 then you can remove it.

Comment: I don't think it matters if you `try` and `catch` on that command. Even if you didn't select the text appropriately it would copy nothing or whatever it is that you actually have selected.

Comment: But this would be not working if when trying to copy email content.

Comment: The `try`/`catch` is needed for older browsers. Some of which will throw an exception instead of a graceful fail.

Answer (score 29):

You can use the new [Clipboard API writeText method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText) which is supported by most modern browsers (see [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_clipboard_writetext) for more details).

```js
//If you want to copyText from Element
function copyTextFromElement(elementID) {
  let element = document.getElementById(elementID); //select the element
  let elementText = element.textContent; //get the text content from the element
  copyText(elementText); //use the copyText function below
}

//If you only want to put some Text in the Clipboard just use this function
// and pass the string to copied as the argument.
function copyText(text) {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
}
```

```html
<div id="mytext">This is some text that needs to be copied</div>
<button onclick="copyTextFromElement('mytext')">Copy</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Great answer by Intervalia.

Small improvement to it, sometimes the clicked element is not the one you want to copy.
So I suggest you pass the id of the element you want to copy.

```
<button onClick='copyText("display")'> Copy </button>
<h1 id='display'> Text Sample </h1>
```

And then, in the first line of your function do

```
element = document.getElementById(element);
```

Not much of a difference but I think it's more useful this way.

Answer (score 2):

`select()` method is used to select the contents of text fields. it won't work on `h1` element.

Answer (score 0):

hi so I looked into it and since you are not using a textInput you cannot just use the `.select()`function. I borrowed some code from a fellow stack overflow developer Jason on how to highlight an item in javaScript

[selecting text in an element akin to highlighting with your mouse.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse)

`function selectedText(element)(){`

```
var doc = document,
text = doc.getElementById(element)
range, selection;

if(doc.body.createTextRange){ 
 range = document.body.createTextRange();
 range.moveToElementText(text);
 range.select(); 
}
else if(window.getSelection){
  selection = window.getSelection();
  range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(text);
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);   
}

return range;
```

I then modified it to return the range.
and with that all you would have to do is

```
document.onclick = function(e){
  if(e.target.className === 'click'){

      var copytext = SelectText('display');
      document.execCommand("copy");
      alert("Copied the text: " + copytext);
   }
}
```

the key part here is that the string passed in to `.execCommand() is lower case 'copy'`

Answer (score -1):

I am using this. This is similar to other answers but seems to be working in Chrome.

```
function CopyToClipBoard(textToCopy) {
var successMessage = 'Success! The text was copied to your clipboard';
var errorMessage = 'Oops! Copy to clipboard failed. ';

// navigator clipboard api needs a secure context (https)
if (navigator.clipboard && window.isSecureContext) {

    // navigator clipboard api method'
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(textToCopy).then(
        function () {
            /* clipboard successfully set */
            console.log(successMessage)
        },
        function () {
            /* clipboard write failed */
            console.warn(errorMessage)
        }
    )
} else
    if (document.queryCommandSupported && document.queryCommandSupported("copy")) {

    // text area method
    var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textarea.value = textarea.textContent = textToCopy;
    textarea.style.opacity = "0"; 

    document.body.appendChild(textarea);
    textarea.focus();
        textarea.select();

        var selection = document.getSelection();
        var range = document.createRange();
        
        range.selectNode(textarea);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);

    try {
        var successful = document.execCommand('copy'); // Security exception may be thrown by some browsers.
        var msg = successful ? console.log(successMessage) : console.warn(errorMessage);
    }
    catch (ex) {
        console.warn(errorMessage, ex);
    }
    finally {
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        document.body.removeChild(textarea);
    }
}
```