# How to make a link copy a predefined text when clicking on it in?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, copy

I'm doing a sample angular app and I have an html file and a typescript file. I made a function in the typescript file to handle the click event to where it copies a specific predefined text and in the html file I just had the function as the onclick event. Is it because I'm using document? The name of the file is blank-blank.component.html and blank-blank.component.ts I have seen other similar questions but it doesn't work for me. Mine is an  tag and the other solutions don't work on this.

```
  myFunction() {
    let copyText = document.getElementById('HI WASSUP') as HTMLInputElement;
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    alert('Copied the log link:' + copyText.value);
    console.log('F');
  }

<a pTooltip="Click to copy to clipboard" style="cursor:pointer" id ="HI WASSUP" value="HI WASSUP" click="myFunction()"> Copy Text </a>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47931843/javascript-copy-to-clipboard-not-working/47932145#47932145

Comment: In angular, you should use `(click)="myFunction()"` rather than just `click="myFunction()"

Comment: @Intervalia that solution doesn't work. Maybe cuz its an <a> tag?

Comment: Since it is an `<a>` tag you may need to call the equivalent of `evt.preventDefault()` to prevent the `<a>` tag from trying to navigate.

Comment: Also remove the space in the `id`